# how can i add comments to to a custom page

Tags: wordpress, comments, posts

I am trying to display the comments of a post in a custom page in wordpress. I want to display all the comments including sub-comments. There is any way to display the comments of corresponding post?the_comments() shows all the comments in the database. Can I use get_the_commets($args)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_comments() would do the trick for you.

```
$comments = get_comments(array('post_id'=>YOUR_ID));
```

will return you an array of comments for particular post.

You can check [get_comments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) page for more options